# What is latest ASP.NET version that comes with VS 2015 update 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a web application using what I think it is the latest version of ASP.NET. I updated my VS 2015 to VS 2015 Update 3 and I am not sure whether I have latest version of ASP.NET and other dependencies or not...

This is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGeneration",
    "watch": "Microsoft.Dnx.Watcher"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

And the DNX SDK Version I am using is 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Is all correct or am I missing an update in my project?

If I am missing a newer version could you please tell me how to upgrade?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNX was discontinued.
On RC2 already it was moved to the .NET CLI: [dot.net](http://dot.net)

The final release was [out a couple months](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/27/announcing-asp-net-core-1-0/) ago:
[ASP.NET Core 1.0](http://www.asp.net/core).

[Here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html) you can find the docs.asp.net instructions on how to migrate from RC1 (DNX) to ASP.NET Core 1.0